# Android Webview on Phonegap

Tags: android, html, cordova, iframe, android-webview

we are developing an Android application with a built-in browser; in the meantime we'd like to produce a working HTML5 mockup to show our partners how the app works.
The only problem is that the iframe I use as the buil-in browser fails to load a variety of sites such as Facebook, google, etc, due to their security policies; can I Phonegap my HTML5 app and have a native controller instead of the iframe that could open any web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phonegap allows you to load external webpages.  You need to whitelist the URL in the config.xml.  You can load the external webpage using either Java or Javascript.

Using Java you would do something like

```
public class ProductFeedback extends DroidGap {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // load with on activity creation with Java
    super.loadUrl("www.facebook.com");

    // or load local page where javascript loads the external page
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
}
```

...
using javascript

```
window.onload() = function() {
    window.location.href = "http://www.facebook.com";
}
```